# Highstock without scroll navigator jumps

Tags: highcharts

I have weird problem with histock chart with data containing big value diferences. When i move selected area in navigator from small values area to big values area with disabled scroll, navigator not scales correctly. Howto solve this problem? I want chart with no animation and scroll.

```js
$(function () {

    $.getJSON('http://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=aapl-c.json&callback=?', function (data) {
        
        for(var i=0; i<data.length ; i++){
          if(i < data.length/2) {
            data[i][1] = 5;
          } else {
            data[i][1] = 50000000000000;
          }
        }
        
        $('#container').highcharts('StockChart', {
   animation: false,
            rangeSelector : {
                selected : 1
            },
            title : {
                text : 'AAPL Stock Price'
            },
            yAxis: {
                opposite:false
            },
            scrollbar: {
          enabled: false
            },
           rangeSelector: {
             enabled: false
           },
            series : [{
                name : 'AAPL',
                data : data,
                tooltip: {
                    valueDecimals: 2
                }
            }]
        });
    });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/ch38kj15/4/

Steps to reproduce:

1. Set range in area marked with (1)
2. Move selected range to area marked with (2). Long labels from chart makes chart and navigator smaller but one container in navigator (3) not scalling like rest.
3. Move selected range to other place in area (2). In this moment when left mouse button is down and move selected range a litle navigator is scaling and selected range is moving and line (3) scales correctly.

[image: step 1 and 2]

[image: step 2]

[image: step 3]

Comment: Hi @Exit196, Could you describe more precisely what the problem is? I do not see any differences with disabled and enabled `scrollbar`.

Comment: I updated my question with steps and screens.

Comment: Thank you @Exit196 for the clarification. That seems to be a Highstock bug, so could you report it as a github issue here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/new ? As a workaround you can set some fixed chart margin: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xw362fkz/

Comment: I created github issue: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/12573